# When the tab opens, the countdown begins

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a wordpress plugin. When I click on a private protected link, it opens a new private page. When the time on this page is complete, the destination is redirected to the URL.

What I'm stuck with here is that when the new tab opens, the timer starts. I want this countdown to start when the user opens that tab.

Let the timer start when you switch to the newly opened tab. Below is the code for the timer I use.

My problem is that the countdown starts immediately after it opens in the new tab. I want the countdown to begin after the user clicks that tab.

```js
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          myFunction();
        });

        var myVar;

        function myFunction() {
          myVar = setInterval(start, 1000);
        }

        function myStopFunction() {
          clearTimeout(myVar);
        }

        document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
            if (document.hidden){
              document.title = "Countdown stopped!";
              myStopFunction();
              document.getElementById("infos").textContent = ""+count+". Saniye içinde sayfayı terk ettiniz. Geri sayım devam ediyor.";
              
            } else {
              document.title = "Starting countdown..";
              myFunction();
            }

        });

        var count = <?php echo $getTimeDecode; ?>;
        function start(){
          var countdown = document.getElementById("numbers").textContent = --count;
          if(countdown === 0){
            window.location = "<?php echo $getURLDecode; ?>";
          }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Just don't call myFunction() on document ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

This will trigger myFunction() once DOM is ready.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/